# Discord.js v14 Attachment not showing in Embed

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a command which has an attachment option, which then puts that image into an embed. For this, I've used this;

```
if(interaction.options.getAttachment('image') == !null) {
var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
.setImage(`${interaction.options.getAttachment('image').url}`);
} else {
var embed = new EmbedBuilder()
.setTitle('No Image');
}
```

in the embed builder where 'image' is the name of the option.

However, it does not show up in the embed. It had worked once but now it isn't, and I'm not sure as to why.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `if(interaction.options.getAttachment('image') !== null) {` instead of `if(interaction.options.getAttachment('image') == !null) {` on the first line. By using `!null` you're basically saying that `interaction.options.getAttachment('image')` should be equal to `true` as `!null` equals to `true` and the `getAttachment` function returns the `Attachment` class and not a `boolean`.